# Why is log-of-sum-of-exponentials $f(x)=\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n e^ {x_i}\right)$ a convex function for $x \in\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

How to prove $f(x)=\log\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}\right)$ is a convex function?

**EDIT1:** for above function $f(x)$, following inequalities hold:

$$\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}\leqslant f(x)\leqslant\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}+\log n$$

and I have tried proving its convexity via definition of a convex function with above inequalities, but that didn't work.

**EDIT2**: I have posted my answers below.

Comment: Composition rules for preserving convexity. But it didn't work

Comment: What about using induction?

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416837/the-second-derivative-of-log-left-sum-limits-i-1nex-i-right-seems-neg

Comment: @MathLover : It seems that I need to compute the Hessian of $f(x)$ that I tried to avoid before.

Comment: @Finley At this moment, I can't think of any other way to prove that the function is convex. The individual entries of the Hessian matrix are given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416837/the-second-derivative-of-log-left-sum-limits-i-1nex-i-right-seems-neg. A proof is also given based on the C-S inequality.

Comment: @Finley The Hessian matrix is also given in https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/functions.pdf (check the 10th slide). A proof (based on the C-S inequality) is also given there.

Comment: @MathLover : Thanks for your patience! I get it.

Comment: The convexity of the log-sum-exp function can also be proved using the gradient inequality and the Hessian criterion (the Hessian is PSD). All you need is the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for both.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Proof:

Let $u_i=e^ {x_i} ,v_i=e^ {y_i}$. So $f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)=\log(\sum_ {i=1}^n e^{\theta x_i + (1-\theta)y_i})=\log(\sum_ {i=1}^n u_i^ \theta v_i^{(1-\theta)})$

From Hölder's inequality:

$$\sum_ {i=1}^n x_iy_i \le (\sum_ {i=1}^n|x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} \cdot (\sum_ {i=1}^n|y_i|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$ where $1/p+1/q=1$.

Applying this inequality to $f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)$:
$$\log(\sum_ {i=1}^n u_i^ \theta v_i^{(1-\theta)}) \le 
\log[(\sum_ {i=1}^n u_i^ {\theta \cdot \frac{1}{\theta}})^ \theta \cdot 
(\sum_ {i=1}^n v_i^ {1-\theta \cdot \frac{1}{1-\theta}})^ {1-\theta}]$$
The right formula can be reduced to:

$$\theta \log\left(\sum_ {i=1}^n u_i\right)+(1-\theta)\log \left(\sum_ {i=1}^n v_i \right)$$

Here I regard $\theta$ as $\frac{1}{p}$ and $1-\theta$ as $\frac{1}{q}$.

So I achieve that $f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y) \le \theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)$.

Answer (score 16):

It is enough to show that 
$$\frac{1}{2} \log (\sum \exp x_i) + \frac{1}{2}\log (\sum \exp y_i)\ge \log (\sum \exp\frac{x_i+y_i}{2})$$
or, with the substitution $\exp\frac{x_i}{2} = a_i$, $\exp\frac{y_i}{2} = b_i$
$$(\sum a_i^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\sum b_i^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ge \sum a_i b_i$$

Comment: This is much nicer than the other answers!

Comment: @user1551:  Thanks!   I heard about it online, also that it's somehow hard to get... turns out it's just an old friend of ours...

Comment: It looks like you applied the definition of convexity? $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y)$. But what is the $\frac{1}{2}$ in this case? It seems that it's $\lambda$? If so, why do you fix $\lambda$ instead of leaving it generic?

Comment: @David: once it works for $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$, one can show that it works for any $\lambda\in [0,1]$, using the continuity of $f$.  It is a standard fact for convex functions. The case of general $\lambda$ is equivalent to Holder's inequality, so that would be an alternate approach.

Comment: @orangeskid Any chance you can provide a citation for this $\lambda=1/2$ trick? Seems like it could be useful to prove convexity in many cases.

Comment: @a06e:maybe  Inequalities by Hardy et al. ?

Answer (score 6):

Another way to prove the convexity of this function is to use the Jensen's Inequality which states that a function is convex if and only if

$$f(tX+(1-t)Y) \le t f(X) + (1-t)f(Y)$$

Now let $X$ be represented by the vector $({X_1, X_2, X_3,... X_n})$,

and let $Y$ be represented by the vector $({Y_1, Y_2, Y_3,... Y_n})$

Let $t = \dfrac{1}{2}$

$$f(tX+(1-t)Y) = \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{\frac{X_i+Y_i}{2}}\right)$$

$$\text{RHS} = \frac{1}{2} \log\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} e^{X_i}\right)+ \frac{1}{2} \log\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} e^{Y_i}\right)$$

$$\text{RHS} = \frac{1}{2} \log\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} e^{X_i}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} e^{Y_i}\right)$$

RHS contains more cross product terms than the LHS thus making it larger than LHS and hence the function is convex.

Comment: How to prove Jensen's inequality holds when $0 \le t \le 1$ more than $t=1/2$?

Comment: According to definition of function  convexity. $f(x)$ is convex if and only if Jensen's inequality holds for any $t \in [0,1]$

Comment: what t=(0,1) suggests is that you are taking a point in between X and Y vector.  For any value of t between two point would range from 0-1.  It not only applies for t= .5 but also any t within (0,1) which is essentially what you want

Comment: (+1) It is also a consequence of CS-inequality: $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{X_i/2}e^{Y_i/2} \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{X_i} \right)^{1/2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{Y_i} \right)^{1/2} $$ This suggests that for general $t \in [0, 1]$ the same proof works by using Hölder's inequality instead.

Comment: I don't follow. Why is $\log(\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{X_i+Y_i}2})=\frac12\log(\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{X_i})+\log(\sum_{i=1}^ne^{Y_i})$?

Comment: it is not equal but less than or equal to (I have evaluated RHS and LHS separately

Comment: Oh, I see. You are trying to reduce the problem statement. OK, thanks.

Comment: You have only shown midpoint convexity

Answer (score 6):

This answer is similar to the answer written by @Nicholas, but I'm including more details.

A nice fact about the `logSumExp` function $f$ is that its gradient is the softmax function $S$:
$$
\nabla f(x) = S(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{e^{x_1}}{e^{x_1} + \cdots + e^{x_n}} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{e^{x_n}}{e^{x_1} + \cdots +e^{x_n}} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The Hessian of $f$ is the matrix $S'(x)$, and a nice fact about the softmax function is that
$$
S'(x) = \text{diag}(S(x)) - S(x) S(x)^T.
$$
If we can show that $S'(x)$ is positive semidefinite, it will follow that $f$ is convex.

**Edit:** At this point, I recommend reading @Bruno-84’s proof, which is superior to the argument that I gave below.

Original argument:

In other words, we need to show that if $v \in \mathbb R^n$, then $v^T S'(x) v \geq 0$. But notice that
\begin{align}
& v^T S'(x) v \geq 0 \\
\iff & v^T \text{diag}(S(x)) v \geq v^T S(x) S(x)^T v \\
\iff & \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{e^{x_i}}{e^{x_1} + \cdots + e^{x_n}}\right) v_i^2 \geq (S(x)^T v )^2 \\
\iff & \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{e^{x_i}}{e^{x_1} + \cdots + e^{x_n}}\right) v_i^2 \geq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \cdot \frac{e^{x_i}}{e^{x_1} + \cdots + e^{x_n}} \right)^2 \\
\iff & \left(\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i} v_i^2 \right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}\right) \geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i e^{x_i} \right)^2
\end{align}
This last inequality is true, as can be seen by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the vectors
$$
a = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{e^{x_1}} \\ \vdots \\ \sqrt{e^{x_n}} \end{bmatrix},
\quad b = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \sqrt{e^{x_1}} \\ \vdots \\ v_n \sqrt{e^{x_n}} \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: So detailed!!! Thanks for the brilliant answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a multivariate function to be convex, it's equivalent to show that its Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite. That is, you can calculate $\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x})$ here and show it is positive semi-definite.

This can be proved using Cauchy Schwarz inequality as shown [here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/teaching/w10/367.w10/367miscfiles/pages48to60.pdf).

Comment: If anyone doesn't understand how CS-inequality is applied at the end of the linked slide, Boyd's book section 3.1.5 has a proof on this as well.

Comment: I also just posted an answer here that gives more details about this proof, including how the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is applied in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I have a preference for proving that the Hessian matrix is non negative as fully developed by @littleO.
Once you have shown that the gradient is the softmax function $S(x)$ and the Hessian matrix has the expression
$$
\nabla^2 f(x) = \operatorname{diag}(S(x)) - S(x)S(x)^T,
$$
you can simply use the convexity of the real map $t\mapsto t^2$ to conclude that
$\nabla^2 f(x)$ is non negative: Since $S(x)^T v$ is a convex linear combination of the coordinates of the vector $v$ (that is $S(x)_k\geq 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n S(x)_k =1$), one has
$$
v^T S(x) S(x)^T v 
= (S(x)^T v)^2
= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n S(x)_k v_k\right)^2
\leq \sum_{k=1}^n S(x)_k v_k^2 = v^T \operatorname{diag}(S(x)) v.
$$

Comment: This is a great proof.