# Prove that $f(x) = \log(\sum_{k=1}^n\exp(x^Tw_k))$ is convex

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Problem: Prove that $\displaystyle f(x) = \log(\sum_{k=1}^n\exp(x^Tw_k))$ is convex.

My attempt: For $x,y \in D$ and $t \in (0,1)$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
f(tx+(1-t)y) = \log(\sum_{k=1}^n\exp(tx^Tw_k)\cdot \exp((1-t)y^Tw_k))
\end{eqnarray}

Now, I am stuck here since I don't know there exists a inequality
$$\log(a_1b_1 + a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n) \le \log(a_1b_1)+...+\log(a_nb_n).$$
If this inequality exists then the problem will be solved.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please don't use display style math on question titles. See [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233).

Answer (score 2):

- Each of the functions $f_k(x) = \exp(x^Tw_k))$ is log-convex, simply because $\log f_k(x)$ is linear.
- The sum of log-convex functions is again log-convex, see for example [How to prove that the sum of two log-convex functions is log-convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665768/42969).

So $x \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^n\exp(x^Tw_k)$ is log-convex, which means that $f$ is convex.

---

For a direct proof one can proceed as in [Why is log-of-sum-of-exponentials $f(x)=\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n e^ {x_i}\right)$ a convex function for $x \in\mathbb R^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418554/why-is-log-of-sum-of-exponentials-fx-log-left-sum-i-1n-e-x-i-right/3621413#3621413), using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
 f(\frac{x+y}{2}) = \log \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x^Tw_k/2) \cdot \exp(y^T w_k/2)\right) \\
\le \log \left( \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x^T w_k)} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(y^T w_k)}\right) \\
= \frac 12 \left( f(x) + f(y) \right) \, .
$$
This shows that $f$ is midpoint-convex, and therefore convex (since $f$ is continous).