# Help to understand the affirmation about the softmax function.

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis

I found the following information in the link [Why is log-of-sum-of-exponentials $f(x)=\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n e^ {x_i}\right)$ a convex function for $x \in\mathbb R^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418554/why-is-log-of-sum-of-exponentials-fx-log-left-sum-i-1n-e-x-i-right)

> A nice fact about the `logSumExp` function $f$ is that its gradient is the softmax function $S$:
> $$
> \nabla f(x) = S(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{e^{x_1}}{e^{x_1} + \cdots + e^{x_n}} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{e^{x_n}}{e^{x_1} + \cdots +e^{x_n}} \end{bmatrix}.
> $$
> The Hessian of $f$ is the matrix $S'(x)$, and a nice fact about the softmax function is that
> $$
> S'(x) = \text{diag}(S(x)) - S(x) S(x)^T.
> $$

But I don't understand why $D^{2}f = S^{\prime}$ if for instance when $n=2$, I have

$$D^{2}f(x) =  \left(\begin{array}{cc} \frac{e^{x_{1}}e^{x_{2}}}{\left(e^{x_{1}}+ e^{x_{2}}\right)^{2}} & -\frac{e^{x_{1}}e^{x_{2}}}{\left(e^{x_{1}}+ e^{x_{2}}\right)^{2}}  \\
-\frac{e^{x_{1}}e^{x_{2}}}{\left(e^{x_{1}}+ e^{x_{2}}\right)^{2}}  & \frac{e^{x_{1}}e^{x_{2}}}{\left(e^{x_{1}}+ e^{x_{2}}\right)^{2}} 
 \end{array}\right)$$

But $diag (S)$ is a matrix $2\times 2$, which does have the term $\frac{e^{x_{1}}e^{x_{2}}}{\left(e^{x_{1}}+ e^{x_{2}}\right)^{2}} $,   while  $- S(x) S(x)^T$ for me is a real number. so I don't understand how prove this afirmation in this case $n=2$.

Comment: Note that $S(x)$ is a column vector, so $S(x)^T$ is a row vector and $S(x) S(x)^T$ is a square matrix.

Comment: Presumably you meant $D^2f(x)$, not $Df$?

Comment: Thanks! I understand @littleO.

Comment: Thanks! @cooper.hat I already corrected.