# Convexity of softmax logistic regression

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning

I am looking for a proof that the multi-class SoftMax logistic regression using Maximum Liklihood has a convex performance function?

In particular I am interested in showing the function:

$$ -ln\Biggl(\frac{e^{{w_i}^T x}}{\sum_{j} e^{{w_j}^T x}}\Biggr) $$

is convex with respect to the weight vectors(I guess all weight vectors need to be considered).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function simplifies to:
$$ \log \left(\sum_{j} e^{{w_j}^T x}\right) - {w_i}^T x.$$
Log-sum-exp is convex (see Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe).

Comment: I see, I read you can also use Jensens Inequality - have any idea how?

Comment: no, the typical convexity proof is based on the Hessian and Cauchy-Schwarz (see Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe).

Comment: The bottom post gives another way: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416837/the-second-derivative-of-log-left-sum-limits-i-1nex-i-right-seems-neg but I am not sure if the final result requires CS or not.